# Why does my page only update when i restart my app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Edit: from the comments apparently i should use a messagingcenter, i am kinda new to xamarin.forms if anyway could help me implement this for my project, i am not sure that i understand how it works after reading the doc.

Currently i have a main page in which i create TasksGroups, and those TasksGroups have a date.
When i create those TasksGroup, the background of the date that are created with the TasksGroups change color.

I am using : https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

In this control it is the SpecialDates that changes the background color of the dates.

**My problem :** Once i create a new TasksGroup ( So a new date is created ) it doesn't automatically change the color the background of the TasksGroupDate on the calendar. The changes takes place when i restart the app.

In my CalendarViewModel the initialize() method is where i set up the background color.

Architecture : TasksGroupPage is my main page and is a TabbedPage, CalendarPage is a ContentPage.

Any idea ? Thanks for help !

To give you an idea of what it looks like :

Mainpage:

[image: main page]

Calendar page :

[image: Calendar page]

**CalendarPage.xaml which i set the BindingContext to CalendarPageViewModel**

```
    <ContentView>
        <controls:Calendar
        Grid.Row="1"
        Padding="10,0,10,0"
        SelectedBorderWidth="4"
        DisabledBorderColor="Black"
        ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
        StartDay="Monday"
        TitleLabelTextColor="#008A00"
        TitleLeftArrowTextColor="#008A00"
        TitleRightArrowTextColor="#008A00"
        SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
        SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"
        DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}"
        DateClicked="DateClicked">

        </controls:Calendar>

    </ContentView>
```

**CalendarPageViewModel.cs I create all the dates that should have a background in the Initialize() method**

```
class CalendarPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        public CalendarPageViewModel()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            
            var taskGroupList = App.Database.GetTaskGroupsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Attendances = new ObservableCollection<SpecialDate>()
            {
                new SpecialDate(DateTime.Now)
                {
                     BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
                     TextColor = Color.Accent,
                     Selectable = true
                },
            };

            taskGroupList.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var sp = new SpecialDate(x.TasksGroupDate)
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                    TextColor = Color.Accent,
                    Selectable = true
                };

                Attendances.Add(sp);
            });

            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }

    }
```

**BaseViewModel.cs **

```
 public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<SpecialDate> attendances;
        public ObservableCollection<SpecialDate> Attendances
        {
            get { return attendances; }
            set 
            { 
                attendances = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
//other properties

}
```

**How i save my TasksGroups in NewtaskPageViewModel**

```
 async Task SaveNewTask()
    {

        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Delay(4000);


        IsBusy = false;

        TasksGroup tasksGroup = new TasksGroup();
        Tasks tasks = new Tasks();

        tasksGroup.TasksGroupDescription = TasksGroupDescription;
        tasksGroup.TasksGroupDate = TasksGroupDate;
        tasks.TaskDuration = TaskDuration;
        tasks.TaskDBA = TaskDBA;
        tasks.TaskDescription = TaskDescription;

        tasksGroup.Taches = new List<Tasks>() { tasks };


        if (ValidateTasksGroup(tasksGroup) && ValidateTasks(tasks))
        {

            await App.Database.SaveTasksGroupAsync(tasksGroup);

            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();


            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }


    }
```

Comment: "Once i create a new TasksGroup" - where is the code that does this?  If this is the problem scenario, why aren't you posting the relevant code?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to have any of the properties for the object, never mind any call to `NotifyPropertyChanged()` for any of those properties. Either you simply have failed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly, or you're missing a lot of code from the question.

Comment: and I still don't understand why you're calling `NotifyPropertyChanged` in `Initialize()`

Comment: @Jason i added the saving method, didn't think it would be the problem because everything works when i create somethings in this page and i called it for Attendances. @ Peter i included the Attendances property which is the one that makes the background changes

Comment: there is nothing in `SaveNewTask` that would update the `Attendances` property that your calendar is bound to.  Saving data to the DB does not automatically update the VM.

Comment: @Jason that could make sens, any idea on how to do this ? Writing an answer so i can upvote would be great ! :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: personally, I would probably use MessagingCenter to send a message to `CalendarPageViewModel` telling it to update

Comment: @Jason could you write an answer with how to do that ? I am not too familiar with messagingcenter, would be greatly appreciated and could give this question an answer. (i'm not sure where to write messagingcenter things )

Comment: @Jason i've read a little about it, where would you put the send and subscribe method ? send probably in SaveNewTask method but subscribe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my answer what i did is only to call my Initialize method in OnAppearing method in my CalendarPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing()
    var vm = this.BindingContext as CalendarPageViewModel;
    vm.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you can send the message in the `SaveNewTask` method:

```
if (ValidateTasksGroup(tasksGroup) && ValidateTasks(tasks))
{

    await App.Database.SaveTasksGroupAsync(tasksGroup);
    
    //Send  updateDate message
    MessagingCenter.Send<Object, TasksGroup>(this, "updateDate", tasksGroup);

    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();


    NotifyPropertyChanged();
}
```

And in your `CalendarPage`, `subscribe` the message and update data there:

```
public partial class CalendarPage : ContentPage
{

    CalendarPageViewModel CalendarPageVM { get; set; }

    public CalendarPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CalendarPageVM = new CalendarPageViewModel();

        this.BindingContext = CalendarPageVM;

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, TasksGroup>(new object(), "updateDate", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + arg, "OK");

            //Update date here , arg here is the new tasksGroup you created in the SaveNewTask method

            TasksGroup tasks = arg as TasksGroup;

            var sp = new SpecialDate(tasks)
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                TextColor = Color.Accent,
                Selectable = true
            };

            CalendarPageVM.Attendances.Add(sp);

        });
    }
}
```

Refer: [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Comment: Thanks for reply, this didn't work. But i am curious to why we subscribe in the xaml.cs file of CalendarPage and not in the CalendarPageViewModel, aren't we doing those operations in the viewmodel file ? ( creating the new special date, etc) Thanks.

Comment: With your implementation before, i didn't get the display message when saving now i did the subscribe stuff in OnAppearing method ( overrided)  and when i save a new TasksGroup i get the display message : arg = Calculette.Models.TasksGroup

Comment: Yes, you get the TasksGroup  and then you can save it to CalendarPageVM.Attendances.